# Main Navigation Submenu Hidden Behind Page Content - Can't Figure Out Why

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, z-index

The main navigation submenu items appear behind the content on this [one page](https://familyofficenetworks.com/events/). It must have to do with the custom page template but I see no z-index values that are interfering. This doesn't happen on the sticky header, only on the main header that is visible when you haven't scrolled down.

When I add z-index values to the header and submenu plus position:inherit (and others) it does not help. The offending section begins with the code below.

```
 <div style="margin-bottom:35px;margin-top: 20px;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew! Played around with the position element and 'fixed' it :)

```
.sf-menu > .financity-normal-menu ul { position: fixed !important; }
```

I added this to just this page b/c other pages are not affected and the issue is now resolved on both desktop & mobile. It was set to:

```
position: absolute
```

which apparently does more than I know. Thank you for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why, and I don't think it's a problem with z-index or positions. Probably because of all the classes that are being added and the fact that the header duplicates when page is scrolled down.

But here's one solution for you. It will make the header stay in one state and *not* transform when page is being scrolled. I also used `@media only screen and (min-width 1000px)` as breaking point because thats when your website's adaptive CSS changes. So we practically don't make any changes for the mobile CSS.

```
@media only screen and (min-width 1000px) {
.financity-header-style-plain {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
} }
```

And I also noticed that on mobile your sidebar menu is hidden behind other content when you scroll down, so add `z-index` to this element:

```
.mm-menu.mm-offcanvas.mm-current {
z-index: 90;
}
```

Comment: Yup this is some weirdness for sure. I'll work on this site later today and report back. Thanks for looking at it!